# How to added a favorites button to details that will save and display them in favorites page in a flutter App

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-test

I have a GridView in My App with elements, every element has it own details, and i want to add the favorite button in each detail page.
but i want to do it locally and permanently, so that the user after exiting the app will find the next time.
(I'm searching for a clear example or a simple)

Answer (score 0):

you can use Shared preferences plugin in your app and store bool value as favorite. if it is null or false show it as not favorite or if it is true show it as favorite.

Add this to your package's pubspec.yaml file:

dependencies:
shared_preferences: ^0.5.8
then import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart' in your dart file and use this code..

```
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  List<Objects> _listData; //instead of this use your data here;
  bool _favStatus=false; // status to show favorite or not
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        child: GridView.builder(itemCount: _listData.length,
          gridDelegate:
              SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(crossAxisCount: 3),
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            checkFavStatus( _listData[index].name);
                        return Container(height: 100, width: 100,
                        child:IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.favorite,color:_favStatus?Colors.red:Colors.black),
                         onPressed: (){setFav(_listData[index].name,_favStatus);},
                         ),
                       );
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              }
            
              void checkFavStatus(String name)async {
                 SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
                 var boolValue = prefs.getBool(name);
                 if(boolValue==null||boolValue==false){
                   _favStatus=false;
                 }
                 else{
                   _favStatus=true;
                 }
              }

              void setFav(String name,bool _currentFavStatus){
                SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
                prefs.setBool(name,!_currentFavStatus);
                setState(() {
                  
                });
              }
}
```

Comment: Thank's for your response, i tried to reproduce it and replace it with my data, but in getBool i got this error "The method 'getBool' isn't defined for the type 'Future'.
Try correcting ..." ?